# How can i place the UITextView auto-complete bubble?

Tags: iphone, autocomplete, uitextview, hidden

I placed `UITextView` for simple chat app.

But the auto-complete bubble was hidden by keyboard.

How can i place the auto-completion bubble on top of the `UITextView`'s input?

[image: Hidden UITextview auto-completion bubble]

Comment: Can you try `[textViewSuperView bringSubviewToFront:textView]`? Here `textViewSuperView` is your textview's super view

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

UITextView frame is bigger than original show size.

In the screenshot image, the UITextView frame is more bigger than one line size. (it was hidden by superview and keyboard)

So the bubble is placed below keyboard.

If we resize UITextView frame to one line size, then the bubble will be show on top.